# How to trigger a class-targeted method AFTER the class has been added to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below markup, the `#enable` button will add a class to the `#show` div. This class has a method attached to it that fades in/out the `#hidden` span.

However, even though the class is added to the `#show` div, the method attached to the class isn't triggered.

**HTML**

```
<input type='button' id='enable' value='Enable' />

<div id='show'>
Testing.. <span id='hidden'>Testing, 1, 2, 3.</span>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    // Adds .testing class after the button is clicked. however..
    $('#enable').click(function() { 
        $('#show').addClass('testing')
    });

    // It will not trigger after .testing class has been added to DIV?            
    $('.testing').hover(function() { 
        $('#hidden').fadeIn(); 
    }, function() {
        $('#hidden').fadeOut(); 
    });
});​
```

Fiddle to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/jS3nM/

It seems I am missing something conceptually. What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does not work like CSS. When you do, `$("selector")`, it will return a list of elements in the document that match that selector right now.

You will then operate on those elements with jQuery methods. There is no magic like "class-targeted method" going on.

You can find add a event listener to `document`:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('#hidden').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#hidden').fadeOut();
    }
}, ".testing");
```

`document` is always found and always exists, and the event listener is added to that. The selector at the end filters out what elements are qualified for the event.

Comment: How to handle it if the method is jQuery's `resizable` or `draggable` method, which includes options?

Comment: @Chase you'll need to call that method on elements that haven't had that method called on. Think in elements, not selectors. When you create a new element that needs to be resizable, you need to call resizable on it. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: I think I understand, however I'm confused about the syntax for an event that requires options. For example, instead of `mouseenter`, I would use `resizable`. So, `$(document).on({ resizable: /* how are options added? */ }, '.testing');`

Comment: @Chase err, `resizable` is a method. `"mouseenter"` is an event. There is no way you can do that.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for my confusion. Under what event should I define `$('.testing').resizable();`? In other words, I want the resizable method attached to an element when it inherits a new class.

Comment: @Chase You should `$(".testing").resizable()`, when there is elements in the document that match such selector. When you do `$('.testing')`, elements that match that selector right now are selected, and you call `resizable` on them. In your code, you would do that like: `$('#show').addClass('testing').resizable()`. There is no need to select the element again, since it would just return  the same element that was already selected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15242/discussion-between-chase-and-esailija)

Answer (score 1):

Because when you bind the `hover` handler there is no element with class of `testing` in the document, you should delegate the event,  you can use the `on` method, try the following"

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.testing', function(e) { 
        $('#hidden').fadeIn(); 
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.testing', function(e) { 
        $('#hidden').fadeOut(); 
});
```

Comment: How to handle it if the method is jQuery's `resizable` or `draggable` method, which includes options?

Comment: @Chase This is not the case for `resizable` and `draggable` methods, as they are not events, you can select the target element and simply call the methods.

Comment: Note that as of v1.8 `"hover"` as shorthand for `"mouseenter mouseleave"` has been deprecated. (The `.hover()` function has not been deprecated, though it isn't suitable for the current problem.)

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for the info, where this has been noted? and why it's not suitable for the current problem?

Comment: because it doesn't use event delegation, none of the direct "event methods" do, such as `.click(), .mousemove()` etc What would they delegate to? implicitly to `document` like `.live`? That didn't turn out too well ;)

Comment: The deprecation of "hover" as a parameter to `.on()` is buried in the middle of the `.on()` documentation page. You can still code the way you did in the original version of your answer by using `.on("mouseenter mouseleave")` and testing `if (e.type == 'mouseenter')`... (Or for now keep using "hover", since it has been deprecated but not yet _removed_.)

Comment: @Esailija I have used `on`, I haven't used a direct `event` method.

Comment: @Raminson I was referring to why `.hover` (the direct method nnnnn mentioned) is not applicable here, sorry for confusion.